# Create a new array with Timesteps and multiple features, e.g for LSTM

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

Hi I am using numpy to create a new array with timesteps and multiple features, for an LSTM.

i have looked at a number of approaches using strides and reshaping but haven't managed to find an efficient solution.

Here is a function that solves a toy problem, however i have 30,000 samples, each with 100 features.

```
    def make_timesteps(a, timesteps):
        array = []
        for j in np.arange(len(a)):
            unit = []
            for i in range(timesteps):
                unit.append(np.roll(a, i, axis=0)[j])
            array.append(unit)
        return np.array(array)
```

`inArr = np.array([[1, 2], [3,4], [5,6]])`

inArr.shape => (3, 2)

`outArr = make_timesteps(inArr, 2)`

outArr.shape => (3, 2, 2)

```
    assert(np.array_equal(outArr, 
           np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[3, 4], [5, 6]], [[5, 6], [1, 2]]])))
```

=> True

Is there a more efficeint way of doing this (there must be!!) can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick would be to append last `L-1` rows off the array and append those to the start of the array. Then, it would be a simple case of using the very efficient [`NumPy strides`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides). For people wondering about the cost of this trick, as we will see later on through the timing tests, it's as good as nothing.

The trick leading upto the final goal that would support both forward and backward striding in codes would look something like this -

Backward striding :

```
def strided_axis0_backward(inArr, L = 2):
    # INPUTS :
    # a : Input array
    # L : Length along rows to be cut to create per subarray

    # Append the last row to the start. It just helps in keeping a view output.
    a = np.vstack(( inArr[-L+1:], inArr ))

    # Store shape and strides info
    m,n = a.shape
    s0,s1 = a.strides

    # Length of 3D output array along its axis=0
    nd0 = m - L + 1

    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided    
    return strided(a[L-1:], shape=(nd0,L,n), strides=(s0,-s0,s1))
```

Forward striding :

```
def strided_axis0_forward(inArr, L = 2):
    # INPUTS :
    # a : Input array
    # L : Length along rows to be cut to create per subarray

    # Append the last row to the start. It just helps in keeping a view output.
    a = np.vstack(( inArr , inArr[:L-1] ))

    # Store shape and strides info
    m,n = a.shape
    s0,s1 = a.strides

    # Length of 3D output array along its axis=0
    nd0 = m - L + 1

    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided    
    return strided(a[:L-1], shape=(nd0,L,n), strides=(s0,s0,s1))
```

Sample run -

```
In [42]: inArr
Out[42]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

In [43]: strided_axis0_backward(inArr, 2)
Out[43]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [5, 6]],

       [[3, 4],
        [1, 2]],

       [[5, 6],
        [3, 4]]])

In [44]: strided_axis0_forward(inArr, 2)
Out[44]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[3, 4],
        [5, 6]],

       [[5, 6],
        [1, 2]]])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [53]: inArr = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000,10))

In [54]: %timeit make_timesteps(inArr, 2)
    ...: %timeit strided_axis0_forward(inArr, 2)
    ...: %timeit strided_axis0_backward(inArr, 2)
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 33.9 ms per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.1 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.2 µs per loop

In [55]: %timeit make_timesteps(inArr, 10)
    ...: %timeit strided_axis0_forward(inArr, 10)
    ...: %timeit strided_axis0_backward(inArr, 10)
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 152 ms per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 12 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.1 µs per loop

In [56]: 152000/12.1  # Speedup figure
Out[56]: 12561.98347107438
```

The timings of `strided_axis0` stays the same even as we increase the length of subarrays in the output. That just goes to show us the massive benefit with `strides` and of course the crazy speedups too over the original loopy version.

As promised at the start, here's the timings on stacking cost with `np.vstack` -

```
In [417]: inArr = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000,10))

In [418]: L = 10

In [419]: %timeit np.vstack(( inArr[-L+1:], inArr ))
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.41 µs per loop
```

The timings support the idea of stacking to be a pretty efficient one.

Comment: Thanks very much - that really helped, i'd seen as_strided before but couldn't understand it until your example and the link! to get the same order, i used add first line to last, and then np.flip on axis 1. I have edited the question to show my final code.

Comment: @nickyzee I don't think I understand why do you need that `flip`. Is your `make_timesteps` correct, because I coded trying to produce the same results as with `make_timesteps`. With your flip suggestion, my code produces different results than with `make_timesteps`. Clarify on this?

Comment: interesting - the flip is required to make the same output as I get from the original. A visual inspection of the output also confirms this. Not sure why - numpy@latest and py3.5 - my original returns `array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[3, 4],
        [5, 6]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]],

       [[7, 8],
        [1, 2]]])`

Comment: @nickyzee Updated with two versions for both forward and backward striding. Check those out!